# Get table names and pass them to field SELECT

Tags: mysql

I need to pass table names I'm getting by SELECT as FROM parameter to another SELECT.

First, get table names:

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='my_schema'
```

Then, I'm trying to encapsulate:

```
SELECT tmp.`field1` FROM (SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='my_schema') AS tmp
```

trying to get field1 data from every table present.

So what I'm trying to do is: get table name and then get data from certain field of that table, and do so with all tables present.

But I'm getting just

> 1054 - unknown field 'tmp.field1' in 'field list'.

I'm not sure that kind of passing even possible. Is it? Or maybe there is another way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add alias in order to refer `table_name` as `field1`:

```
SELECT tmp.`field1` 
FROM (SELECT table_name AS `field1`
     FROM information_schema.tables 
     WHERE table_schema='my_schema') AS tmp
```

Comment: It's not what I needed to do. Maybe I was unclear in original question, will edit it accordingly.
Still, thank you, your code doesn't end with error.